# Looping through & displaying array in order

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I create a loop or function that will display a new array index on every click. I tried using a for loop but I keep getting only the first value and then when I'll click it'll jump to the last value.

```
var arrow = document.getElementById ('arrow');
var para = document.getElementById ('para');
function textForward (){
  arrow.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var arr = [
     'a','b','c','d'
    ]
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    para.innerHTML = arr[i]
  });
}
```

Each time a button is clicked, the above needs to display the next value of that array in order. (for example, the array will start out at a, then when the user clicks it'll go to b, then on the next click c and so on).

Comment: Yeah this code isn't much to begin with

Comment: Do you have the code for the click handler?

Comment: I'm just asking if there is a way to loop through an array in order, thats all didn't think you needed the code ! I'll update my question now to contain the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, I feel dumb for not figuring this out..Here is the updated code

```
var arrow = document.getElementById ('arrow');
var para = document.getElementById ('para');
let counter = 0;
function textForward (){
    var arr = [
      'How are you?',
      'Are you Ready to play the Game',
      'Here is how it works',
      'you have three hints to guess what I am thinking',
      'Guess wrong and you are out',
      'simple..let the games begin'
    ]



    para.innerHTML = arr[counter];

    counter ++;
}


textForward();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a global counter to track the current index. Something like this

```
var arrow = document.getElementById ('arrow');
var para = document.getElementById ('para');

// The current index
var index = 0;

var arr = ['a','b','c','d'];

arrow.addEventListener('click', function(){
    para.innerHTML = arr[index];
    if(index < arr.length - 1) index++;
});
```

Comment: all good ! Thanks for answering, may I ask what the -1 does in your if statement?

Comment: that way the counter only gets incremented until its equal to arr.length - 1. This is important so it never exceeds the array when you click it over and over again. (An array is indexed 0,1,2,..., length-2, length-1)